# Entry is not public in TreeMap; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: android, java-8

I have change the source compatibility version of android project to 1.8 to support Java 8 features. But after change project is not building. It shows following error:

**error: Entry is not public in TreeMap; cannot be accessed from outside package**

```
for (TreeMap.Entry<Integer, DynamicListItem> entry : dynamicListItemTreeMap.entrySet())
```

Comment: since all you care about an `Entry` actually, just change to `Map.Entry<Integer, DynamicListItem>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only access it from `Map` interface :

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, DynamicListItem> entry : dynamicListItemTreeMap.entrySet()){    
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes this solution works. But can you tell me why this works on 1.7 not in 1.8?

Comment: @rawcoder064 nope, because it should have not happen, always be `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet`

Comment: The problem is that the compiler’s behavior is making code depending on implementation details. If `TreeMap` does not have an internally used, non-`public` class named `Entry`, `TreeMap.Entry` gets resolved to `Map.Entry` due to inheritance. If you try to compile the same code against a class library where `TreeMap` has a non-`public` member type named `Entry`, the code fails. The morale is, `static` members should not be inherited, but this design mistake of the Java language can’t be fixed without breaking backwards compatibility (even more than with this issue).